Unconfirmed Bitcoin Transaction for more than 7 Days
I initiated a Bitcoin transaction from Bitcoin Core to another wallet, and it has remained unconfirmed for more than 7 days. I suspect this is due to the very low transaction fee I set. During the transfer, I selected the option for a 7-day target confirmation time (1008 blocks) with the wallet’s suggested minimum fee. Previously, payments with this setting processed without issues.
How can I cancel the transaction and return the bitcoins to my wallet? To clarify, the transaction is still unconfirmed, with no blocks verified under the hash identifier.
P.S. I am aware of functions to increase the transaction fee to make it more noticeable to miners, but this is no longer relevant for me. I simply want the transaction to be canceled and the coins returned to my wallet.
Thank you.
